# python 3 empty string error

Tags: python, string

In this code i want that if a user enters empty string in the question then the last item should be popped. But in the output it is adding the empty string as a list value.

```
our_list = []
n=int(input("how many values are there in the list?"))
for i in range(0,n):
  x=str(input("enter names of animals for the list"))
  our_list.append(x)
print(our_list)



y=str(input("enter the name of an animal "))

if y in our_list:
  our_list.remove(y)
elif y not in our_list:
  our_list.append(y)
elif len(y)==0:
  our_list.pop()

print(our_list)
```

Comment: Move your `len(y)==0` check as the first check. Also it's better to use `if not y` to check if a string `y` is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sshashank124 is perfectly correct, I will take the liberty to elaborate a bit more. Your first two if's already exhausted all possibilities, thus "len(y)==0:" will never get executed. It is a good practice to check whether y exists by "if y" or "if not y" instead of "len(y) == 0", so your code doesn't break down when you get a None type.

```
if not y:
    our_list.pop()
elif y in our_list:
    our_list.remove(y)
elif y not in our_list:
    our_list.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the empty string "" is not in the list and you are hitting the second condition `elif y not in our_list` and appending to the list. You would ideally want to check for empty string first:

```
if not y: # Checks if string is empty
  out_list.pop() # probably you would like to check if our_list is not empty
elif y in our_list:
  our_list.remove(y)
elif y not in our_list:
  our_list.append(y)
```

Also you don't need `str(input())` as `input` already returns a string.